# position absolute inside position fixed

Tags: html, css

```css
.parent{
position:fixed;
width:140px;
right:0; top:14px;
overflow-y:scroll;
height:140px;
background:lightgreen;
}

.btn{
position:absolute;
left:0; top:14px;
cursor:pointer;
background:gold;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
<div class='btn'>BUTTON</div>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
</div>
```

Why is `btn` scrollable? It is absolute positioned.

So I need to scroll `parent` but `btn` keeping in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `position:sticky;` instaed of `position:absolute;`

```css
.parent{
position:fixed;
width:140px;
right:0; top:14px;
overflow-y:scroll;
height:140px;
background:lightgreen;
}

.btn{
position:sticky;
left:0; top:14px;
cursor:pointer;
background:gold;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
<div class='btn'>BUTTON</div>
lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
</div>
```

Comment: tell for more help

Comment: I see it works in your snippet, but it doesn't work on my page! Can't see the reason.

Comment: plaese look at your F12 style and see if it override

Comment: happy to help :) really appricate if you mark as answer

Comment: Please keep in mind, that `position: sticky` will not work at all in Internet Explorer, and it is only partially supported by Edge, Chrome and Opera!